# How big would an 11 year old's wings have to be to fly?

Tags: creature-design

Would it be possible for a 11 year old to fly with a pair of wings? If so, how big would the wings be? (Width, length, shape, etc)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What would humans wings...](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/39736/6986).

Comment: An 11 year old what, human child? How are the wings attached? Replacing the arms (like a bird/harpy) or growing from the back (like a fairy/angel)? What limitations/requirements do we have to work with? Currently the largest birds like raptors hit 30 pounds or so with 8 foot wingspans. The heaviest bird, the great bustard at 40 pounds, has a 6-8 foot wingspan as well. This is probably half of what an 11 year old weighs though. A pterosaur would be closer in weight, but the anatomy is so different, hard to directly compare.

Comment: @Frostfyre I agree about the duplicate, but I'm curious whether the age restriction would change the outcome.  An adult human wouldn't be able to fly according to Jim2B's answer, but perhaps the slightness of an 11 year old would make it more feasible?  Not sure if that qualifies for a separate question, though.

Comment: What actually matters the most is how fast you want them to be able to fly.  There's a HUGE difference in necessary wing span based on speed of flight.  Flying at a walking pace vs. flying faster than a run is a matter of many feet.  Look at my post (here)[http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/55996/anatomically-correct-pegasus/56029#56029].  You can substitute weight and flight speed for your answer.

Comment: There is a lot of changes needed. You want the height of the 11yo? Body (sans wings) mass of 11yo? Just glide? Start by jumping from a cliff? Running start from flat? How inhuman you want it to be? From "very" to "extremely",  that is? Do you need them to lose ability to fly when they're older? If not, why this specific age?